# Type of droid pulling Anakin and Padme's cart on Tatooine?

Tags: star-wars, droids

In Episode 2, Anakin and Padme go to Tatooine to find Anakin's mother. When they arrive at Watto's place they are in some sort of cart being pulled by a droid.

**Does anyone know the name/type of this droid?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on your description, it looks like you are talking about a rickshaw droid:

[image]

As seen in *Episode II*:

[image]

Wookieepedia calls it an [RIC-series general labor droid](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/RIC-series_general_labor_droid), specifically an RIC-920. However, the only reference to this name appears to be from a deleted page on starwars.com (there's an archived version of it [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20100203064433/http://starwars.com/databank/droid/ric920/index.html)). The novelization of *Episode II* referred to it as an ES-PSA droid.

Comment: Excellent. I knew someone would know the answer!